# Exponent: Failed to publish package

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to publish the app from inside [Exponent](https://getexponent.com), but I'm getting the message "Failed to publish package: API Response Error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object.".

Any ideas why?

(there are no other error logs and the app runs fine with the exp:// link and my computer running it, so I'm not sure what other information would be useful).

Comment: Probably easier to join the Exponent Slack channel for help, the peeps on there are super helpful:  https://slack.exponentjs.com/

Comment: thank you! I needed more characters...